# event for customer address frontend update

Tags: customer, event-observer, shipping-address, customer-address

someone could tell me if there's an event to observe when i update customer address (shipping and billing)? From frontend and backend. I need it to copy these addresses and putting them into another db.

Thanks.

Comment: there are two observer `customer_address_save_before` and `customer_address_save_after` you can use any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an event called `customer_address_save_after` which is used for `afterAddressSave` method in `Mage_Customer_Model_Observer` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's an event. But it's a dynamic event. So you have to open the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php` and put a Mage::log() inside the _beforeSave() function.

```
abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Abstract extends Varien_Object
    {
       /**
         * Processing object before save data
         *
         * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
         */
        protected function _beforeSave()
        {
            if (!$this->getId()) {
                $this->isObjectNew(true);
            }
            Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_before', array('object'=>$this));
            Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
            // Put a log here.
           Mage::log($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before',null,'test.log',true);
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Then you can figure out the event.

Comment: I don't understand, what i have to log! what's the argument of Mage::log() ?

Comment: Updated the answer